# Block address of a contract

Tags: solidity

In solidity we retrieve owner address by using msg.sender, 1.But how to retrieve the block address on which the contract was deployed ?

Comment: Loop through the blocks and look for a contract deployment transaction at the address of the constract. This cannot be done inside a smart contract.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't a "block address", you can retrieve the block number (the closest thing to an address) with `block.number`. This is the block number of the block where the transaction executing your code is included.
You can get the block hash with `blockhash(block_number)` but this cannot work with `blockhash(block.number)` so it's only usable for old blocks (but not too old, maximum 256).

You could add in your constructor a line that stores `block.number` in a public variable of your smart contract.

Generally speaking, internally (i.e. using Solidity or even more generally the EVM), you can see (only a part of) the *current status* of the blockchain. Despite the fact that the entire blockchain is public by nature, it is only if you analyze it externally, not using a smart contract.
So you have to explicitly code these mechanisms.

Comment: And to add onto this, if you wanted to know the block the contract was deployed in, you should record that block number in the contract constructor/initialize method using a storage or immutable variable.